# Radius search for multiple locations with django-haystack and Spatial Solr Plugin

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I have a Person model which now can have a number of office "locations", each with its own latitude/longitude.

Before one could add only 1 office, So i'd been using a fork I made for django-haystack that uses JTeam's spatial-solr-plugin to do radius search. See https://github.com/sidmitra/django-haystack

```
class PersonIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
    lat = indexes.FloatField()
    lng = indexes.FloatField()

sqs.spatial(lat=lat, long=lng, radius=radius, unit=kwargs.get('unit'))
```

Since the number of offices are unlimited, i can't use separate lat/lng fields in the index.

One way i could think of was to index the "Location" model instead. Each location would be a seperate entry in the index. Thus solving this problem, but would mean replicating all of the fields from the Person index to this location index. Although this might be a decent solution in the short term, but would probably be untidy in the long run?

Wondering if there's a way to index locations separately and then filter related Person, based on the addresses that are within the specified radius?